# What are the Moderation Policies for Answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

The policy of each SE site is defined by its community, for each specific site like Buddhism.SE. So in the context of this site what are the Moderation Policies for Answers? Should we just have the same policy as the main StackOverflow (SO) site? What are relevant posts on this in SO? If we are to deviate from SO policy what would they be?

Comment: I think this should be ultimately linked to or covered in the welcome message.

Comment: I'd like to reserve use of the [meta-tag:proposed-faq] tag for actual proposals (not just questions without answers), which might become a [meta-tag:faq]. See e.g. [this meta-answer](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/193/535) fr my understanding of how this works. I'm going to edit the Meta tags soon and I think you'll find we already have several 'accepted' policies about answers, which I will label proposed-faq.